# How to Load large HTML string in WebView with LoadHTMLString method?

Tags: javascript, html, ios, objective-c, uiwebview

I have to load an html string onto the UIWebView with 'LoadHTMLString' method of UIWebView.

Please find the below code.

```
[wv loadHTMLString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no\"><meta charset=\"utf-8\"><title>Traffic layer</title><style>html, body, #map-canvas {height: 100%%;margin: 0px;padding: 0px}</style><script src=\"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp\"></script><script>function initialize() {var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(34.04924594193164, -118.24104309082031);var mapOptions = {zoom: 13,center: myLatlng}var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptiotrafficLayer.setMap(map);}google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);</script></head><body><div id=\"map-canvas\"></div></body></html>"] baseURL:nil]
```

When I load this, my webview is empty, it is not showing anything.

When I put this code into file with the extension 'html' and load on to the webview it is working fine.

Can any one help me in loading this on to the WebView? Or could any one let me know what is going wrong in this code.

Comment: The reason it's not working is because your string is incorrect. If I put that string into a simple html document and try to load that it informs me that there was a syntax error: "**[Error] SyntaxError: Unexpected keyword 'var'. Expected ';' after var declaration.**"
Re-evaluate the string that you're trying to load and make it parse outside of the project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to create one html file and put all html content in it, And use code to load that file

```
[self.webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"filename" ofType:@"html"] isDirectory:NO]]];
```

And using this also

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"filename" ofType:@"html"];
NSString *html = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];

[self.webView loadHTMLString:html baseURL:[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleURL]];
```

**Edit:**

I was overlooked that you have mention that loading file is working perfect.

I think issue is because of you load this string at runtime.

We all know that when we use html and css files we need to add these files in **"Copy Bundle Resources"**. So that it will be available when html page load at runtime.

So may be issue here is some of the functions in that html string are use some file or assistance before it loads. So that's why runtime html creation and loading is not working.

How ever more of clear me if i'm misleading.

You can set runtime values in html file though.

**Exmaple.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>

<body>

#latitude# 

#longitude# 

</body>
<html>
```

See above file, You can add marker like `#latitude#` and `#longitude#` in that file. And replace this at a runtime. Like below code.

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"filename" ofType:@"html"];
NSString *html = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];

html = [html stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"#latitude#" withString:<LATITUDE-VALUE>];
html = [html stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"#longitude#" withString:<LONGITUDE-VALUE>];
```

Comment: He is asking through string ! not file

Comment: @srinivasn - Oh yes that was overlooked.

Comment: Yes, I am looking for loading through string. Because it has Latitude & longitude co-ordinaetes. I wanted to change them according to the selection of the location in my application. That is the reason why I wanted it as a string. This cannot be done if I put it into a file and copy to bundle resource. Suggest me if any alternative for this.

Comment: Yes you can do it with file. I'll give you a solution.

Comment: thank you for your elaborative answer @Kampai, could you please tell me what is 'htmlString' in your answer?

Comment: Its an `NSString` variable to just copy `html` string content with real values in it. You can also use same variable.

Answer (score 1):

After two days, long sleep, I've come up with this.

Swift

```
let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("public_html/index", ofType: "html")
var html = try? NSString(contentsOfFile: path! as String, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
html = html?.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("#latitude#", withString:"<p class=\"text-center\">Center aligned text.</p><blockquote><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer posuere erat a ante.</p></blockquote>")
webView.loadHTMLString(html as! String, baseURL: NSURL(fileReferenceLiteral: "public_html"))
```

First, my HTML code is in my project ( public_html/index.html ). This code loads the HTML, converts it, replaces the tag '#latitude#' and loads the HTML using the directory ( for loading JS, etc.).