# iOS UIWebview does not load new css

Tags: ios, css, html, uiwebview

In my app,I download an **HTML** app and save it in documents directory.I open it using a **UIwebview**. This works fine. But the problem is,if I make any css change on my server and then download the app again,the changes are reflected in documents directory but when I open the app in UIwebview , the changes are not reflected there. If I open the .html file in safari , the css changes work.

I load my html file using the following code:

```
appReq = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:appURL cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData timeoutInterval:20.0];
[self.webView loadRequest:appReq];
```

where  `appURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:"path to downloaded html app in documents directory"];`

I tried to clear the caches using following methods:

```
[[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] removeCachedResponseForRequest:appReq];

and 

 [[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] removeAllCachedResponses];
```

but they do not help.

P.S : The changes are only reflected if I reopen my application.

Does anyone has any clue how to solve this?

Comment: Have a look on this answer. May be it will help you - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26799493/how-to-load-large-html-string-in-webview-with-loadhtmlstring-method/26799555#26799555

Answer (score 0):

You should generate a rendom number and append it to your path (to ignore the cache).

Instead of:

```
appURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:"path to downloaded html app in documents directory"];
```

use:

```
int randomNumber = rand() % 1012074;
appURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@&ignoreCache=%d",<path to downloaded html app in documents directory>,(int)randomNumber]];
```

I hope it will help you!

Good luck!