# How to call HTML file with css, js and images?

Tags: javascript, html, ios, zip, nsurl

I am downloading zip file from server. In NSCachesDirectory I have the html file and I would like to know how to run html file with their source files, I have pasted my code. please help me

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsPath =  [[paths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"/Lesson-file/Lesson%d",[str_lsn_id integerValue]]];

NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"story_html5" ofType:@"html" inDirectory:documentsPath]];
[lsn_play_webview loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url]];
```

Comment: Take a look on this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26799493/how-to-load-large-html-string-in-webview-with-loadhtmlstring-method/26799555#26799555

Comment: Above code is not working for me

Comment: The answer link is an approach, not an exact answer for your problem!. BTW you said that you have source files like css and js. These files are downloaded from server? Or they are hyperlink? Are these files are in same directory with html file?

Comment: All the html,css, js and images are download from server as a folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an approach for you. From the context that you said that you have source files `js` and `css`.

Here issue may be because of on run time these files are not loaded or compiler not able to find their location.

For exmaple:

```
  <!--For CSS file html tag is-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css"> 

  <!--For JS file html tag is-->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="exmample.js"></script>
```

So you have to manually provide location of these files.

See the tags here `href` and `src`. These are location of resource files which will required on runtime when your html page is loaded in memory.

**How ever if these files are in same directory than there is no need to provide url**

**Suggestion:**

It is advisable that you provide file location url here. Edit your html file and add markers for the url tags.

Example code:

```
<html> <head>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="#JS-FILE1#"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="#CSS-FILE1#">

</head> <body> </body>
</html>
```

You can see that I have replaced files with markers `#JS-FILE1#` and `#CSS-FILE1#`. Now we will replace these markers with actual urls before loading html file.

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"filename" ofType:@"html"];
NSString *html = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];

// Location of Resource files
NSString *jsFilePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"exmample" ofType:@"js"];

NSString *cssFilePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"stylesheet" ofType:@"css"];

html = [html stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"#JS-FILE1#" withString:jsFilePath];
html = [html stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"#CSS-FILE1#" withString:cssFilePath];
```

Put here break point and debug the output string. `NSLog` this string copy it and create temporary file - open it in browser to cross check that all resources are loaded or not?

If not then check that url for resource files are correct.