# Load Resource From Xcode Folder in to Html File in WebView

Tags: html, ios, webview, assets

i am newbie in iOS Development, i make an app that contain html data and it is Load In to WebView it is Working Fine but in One Html File I want to Link a Another Html File That are also In my App How i Get him to Path like as an android asset here android asset path is like as

```
<P STYLE="margin-bottom: 0in"><B><a href="file:///android_asset/13 THE AURUM SOLIS TAROT/THE AURUM SOLIS TAROT.html">The representation of the divinities can be found in the Aurum Solis Tarot… </a></B><FONT COLOR="#0070c0">  </FONT></P>
```

Here i want to load Html File From iOS Asset How it Possible Please Give me Solution For this.

Comment: Have a look on this answer - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27059286/how-to-call-html-file-with-css-js-and-images/27061039#27061039

Comment: @Kampai i want to add File Path in my href link not in my web view. when user click on web view href link then i want to open another html file it is also in Xcode (My App.) folder.